# wp_get_attachment_image_src always returns false

Tags: attachments, images, codex

I'm using wp_get_attachment_image_src to retrieve image URL.

Codex is simple for this function and starting from an ID on my database I used `wp_get_attachment_image_src` in this way:

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(2447);

echo $image_url[0];
```

where 2447 is an ID of an attachment in my wp_posts db table (already checked).

Everything seems correct, but trying to execute the code the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` returns always `false`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: try using `wp_get_attachment_url(2447)`

Answer (score 1):

**In function passing a attachment id or thumbnail id NOT post id.**

Try this

```
<?php 

      global $post;
      $attch_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
      $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attch_id);
      echo "<img src='".$url[0]."' />";

    ?>
```

I hope is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way and let me know if it works or not ..

```
<?php
$my_attachment = 2447;
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $my_attachment );?>
<img src="<?php echo $image_url[0] ?>" />
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohil_PHPBeginner. Unfortunately nothing changed. I can't uderstand why, it's really simple PHP and really "stupid" function...

Comment: it worked or not ?? If yes then I edit my answer with explanation.

Comment: No, your suggestion did not work.

Comment: Put that condition `if( $image_url ) {}` and try to debug it and see if we are true or not.

Comment: It returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id = 2447 );
if ( $image_url ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_url[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo image_url[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

SYA